# Convert &apos; to an apostrophe in PHP

Tags: php, html, special-characters, decode

My data has many HTML entities in it (`&bull;` ...etc) including `&apos;`.  I just want to convert it to its character equivalent.

I assumed htmlspecialchars_decode() would work, but - no luck.  Thoughts?

I tried this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode('They&apos;re here.');
```

But it returns:  `They&apos;re here.`

**Edit:**

I've also tried html_entity_decode(), but it doesn't seem to work:

```
echo html_entity_decode('They&apos;re here.')
```

also returns: `They&apos;re here.`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Since `&apos;` is not part of HTML 4.01, it's not converted to `'` by default.

In PHP 5.4.0, [extra flags were introduced](http://php.net/html_entity_decode#refsect1-function.html-entity-decode-parameters) to handle different languages, each of which includes `&apos;` as an entity.

This means you can do something like this:

```
echo html_entity_decode('They&apos;re here.', ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
```

You will need both `ENT_QUOTES` (convert single and double quotes) and `ENT_HTML5` (or any language flag other than `ENT_HTML401`, so choose the most appropriate to your situation).

Prior to PHP 5.4.0, you'll need to use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
echo str_replace('&apos;', "'", 'They&apos;re here.');
```

Comment: I've updated the answer for PHP 5.4.0 (props to eric.itzhak for the update).

Answer (score 8):

There is a "right" way, without using `str_replace` , @cbuckley was right it's because the default for [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) is HTML 4.01, but you can set an HTML 5 parameter that will decode it.

Use it like this:

```
html_entity_decode($str,ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `&apos;` entity and a lot of others are not in the PHP translation table used by  `html_entity_decode` and `htmlspecialchars_decode` functions, unfortunately.

Check this comment from the PHP manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php#73410

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
$value = "They&apos;re here.";
html_entity_decode(str_replace("&apos;","'",$value));
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, but this is the same as the already-approved answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually looking for is [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).

`html_entity_decode()` translates all entities to characters, while `htmlspecialchars_decode()` only reverses what `htmlspecialchars()` will encode.

**EDIT:** Looking at the examples on the page I linked to, I did a bit more investigation and the following seems to not work:

```
[matt@scharley ~]$ php
<?php
$tmp = array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES));
var_dump($tmp['&apos;']);
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: &apos; in - on line 3
NULL
```

This is why it's not working. Why it's not in the lookup table is another question entirely, something I can't answer unfortunately.

Comment: @Dave: Unfortuanately, you may need to roll your own... Seems like PHP doesn't support reversing `&apos;` for some reason. See my edit for more.

Comment: And it seems that was because `&apos;` isn't part of HTML 4.01.

Comment: @cbuckley sound like a likely reason. `&apos;` was pulled into XHTML for compatibility with XML.

Answer (score -5):

Have you tried using `echo htmlspecialchars('They&apos;re here.')`?

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I believe that's opposite of what I want.