# Sybase, I need read &apos; or &quot; and retorn ' or "

Tags: html, t-sql, sybase, decode, encode

I am work in Sybase, [Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0].

My problem is that the form reads special character in HTML and I  need to return the string literal:

For example:

```
select '&apos; &quot;' ->  ' "
```

But in my version of sybase not working `HTML_ENCODE` and `HTML_DECODE`.

Comment: I think the answer might be given in this previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791298/convert-apos-to-an-apostrophe-in-php

Comment: Thank you, in this moment I resolved with remplace too, but I don't exists other way